# Password match validation in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone explain how this password match is working? I went through the documents but got confused with `require:ngModel` controller.

Inside the script, what these three lines mean:

1. var originalModel = $parse(attrs.valueMatches),
2. secondModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
3. ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, newValue === secondModel(scope));

Is the `attrs.ngModel` here refering to the ngModel controller or the directive?

Is `attrs.ngModel` fetching the attributes of first input field or confirming password input field?

`attrs.name` - I don't see any `name` attribute in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

        <script>
            "use strict";
            var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

            app.directive('valueMatches', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
                    return {
                        require: 'ngModel',
                        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ngModel) {
                            var originalModel = $parse(attrs.valueMatches),
                                    secondModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
                            // Watch for changes to this input
                            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue) {
                                ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, newValue === originalModel(scope));
                            });
                            // Watch for changes to the value-matches model's value
                            scope.$watch(attrs.valueMatches, function (newValue) {
                                ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, newValue === secondModel(scope));
                            });
                        }
                    };
                }]);
        </script>

        <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2>
            <div>
                <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" novalidate>
                    First name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="uname" placeholder="First Name" required/>

                    Password:<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd" ng-model="pwd" required />

                    Confirm Password: <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-model="pwd2" value-matches="pwd" required/>
                    <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pwd2.$dirty && myForm.pwd2.$invalid">Passwords did not match<br></span><br>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zCxRp71SICuYp1JDm3pY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Inside the script, what these three lines mean:

1. var originalModel = $parse(attrs.valueMatches),
   **Response:** this is taking the value of the `value-matches="pwd"` in the `<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-model="pwd2" value-matches="pwd" required/>`
2. secondModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
   **Response:** this is taking the vale of `ng-model` in the same `<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-model="pwd2" value-matches="pwd" required/>`. ***all ngModel's and attrs in directives are local***
3. ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, newValue === secondModel(scope));
   **Response:** This watcher is checking the newVal of `attrs.valueMatches` and then setting the validity of whatever form-control with the same name as `attrs.name`(essentially validating itself in this case since its the only form-control in the directive). The validity is determined by the boolean comparison between the `ng-model` and `value-matches` in `<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-model="pwd2" value-matches="pwd" required/>`

   attrs.ngModel means it is talking about ngModel controller or directive?
   **Response :** same as above, directives are used to create isolated scopes so unless there is a controller included in the directive every thing will be contained locally in the directive.

Also attrs.ngModel is fetching the attributes of first input field or confirm password input field?
**Response:** Above again, its local so that means its only pulling the ng-model of the element containing the attribute `value-matches`. Directives get translated in the view from `valueMessages` => `value-messages`

attrs.name - I don't see any name attribute in the code?
**Response:** `name="pwd2"` in `<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-model="pwd2" value-matches="pwd" required/>` is `attrs.name`.

I hope this helps you. Directives can be **VERY CONFUSING** at first but stick with it! They are also **EXTREMELY USEFUL** and you will grow to love them...in time.

Comment: I didn't understand when you said "all ngModel's and attrs in directives are local"

Comment: `attrs.name` here is the name of the validator right? So I can give any name instead of `attrs.name`?

Comment: What I meant by local is which ever element (in this case `<input>` that is defined with the directive (in this case uses the attribute `value-matches=` generates a new isolate scope unique to itself. So the only ngModel it is referencing is the one associated with itself. The reason you need require:ngModel for an input direct is so you can inherit all of the angular functionality associated with ngModel.

Comment: attrs.name here is the `name=` identifier of the input. Are you familiar with naming forms and form inputs? You cannot give any name instead of attrs.name, you can use any name ( `name="email"` or `name=special`) to identify the input.

Answer (score 0):

`require:ngModel` means that this custom directive depends on another directive `ng-model` here.

Normally, link function of a directive takes only three parameters, scope, element and attributes, in the same order. When you specify a require property, directive takes a fourth parameter, controller of the required directive. So, you have received `ngModelController' here in`ngModel` of directive.

```
var originalModel = $parse(attrs.valueMatches)
```

Here, we are retrieving the original model or ng-model value of the first input box and storing it in originalModel.

```
secondModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
```

Similarly, here we are retrieving value for the second model and storing in `secondModel`

`attrs.ngModel` represents value `pwd2` which will store the value entered by user in confirm password input box. And using `$parse`, we are retrieving this value from the controller scope.

Now, later, we put a `$watch` on both the variables, to monitor changes in both the values.

An input at any given time can have fallowing states.

`$pristine` -> Input has not been touched.

`$dirty` -> User has changed input.

`$valid` -> Input contains a valid value.

`$invalid` -> Input contains an invalid value.

With this line:

```
ngModel.$setValidity(attrs.name, newValue === secondModel(scope));
```

we are effectively setting the validation state (`$valid` or `$invalid`) depending upon equality of these two ng-model values.

If both are same, result will be true -> `$valid`

And if result if false -> `$invalid`

Comment: Some people call the fourth attribute differenty Example: `link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl)` or may be `link: function (scope, elm, attrs, model)`. It doesn't matter how we call the controller? How would we know if we are calling controller if we use different names